# Can we extract week numbers from the date

Tags: r

I got a dataframe df. Is there a way to populate the week numbers (as shown the second column in the dataframe). I mean the week numbers should be continuous. For example.

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1527120000, 1527206400, 1527292800, 
1527379200, 1527465600, 1527552000, 1527638400, 1527724800, 1527811200, 
1527897600, 1527984000, 1528070400, 1528156800, 1528243200, 1528329600, 
1528416000, 1528502400, 1528588800, 1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 
1528934400, 1529020800, 1529107200, 1529193600, 1529280000, 1529366400, 
1529452800, 1529539200, 1529625600, 1529712000, 1529798400, 1529884800, 
1529971200, 1530057600, 1530144000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Week = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Here the first date is `24-05-2018` and hence it should be numbered as 1. The number should be continued for the next 6 days and then 2 should start for the next 7 days. After 4 week, the number should not be again 1, the number should be numbered as 5 and so on. So basically I need to check the mean of the list of time series for the span of 4 years. So right from day 1(say in 2000) to last day (say in 2014), the week number should be populated. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gl`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(Week = as.integer(gl(n(), 7, n())))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this answer :). But the week number start from 1 (you can refer my dataframe (column 2)). I know the actual weeknum is 21, but my intention is not that. It Should start from 1. Like it should be (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3 and so on).....

Comment: But I did not get ````as.integer(gl(n(), 7, n())))```` this code

Comment: @DevP it is to create a grouping index at each 7 row, i.e. for the first 7, it would be 1, then 2, etc.. until the end..

Answer (score 2):

Date values are basically the number of seconds since a particular date. Here we can calculate the week offset with a bit of modulo math

```
df %>% 
  mutate(NewWeek = as.numeric(Date-min(Date)) %/% (60*60*24*7) + 1)
```

We subtract off the first date, then see how many seven day periods have passed.

Comment: Elegant solution using modular arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
df$Data <- trunc((ymd(df$Date) - min(ymd(df$Date)))/dweeks(1)) + 1
```

`1` is needed to start numbering of weeks from 1. `trunc` gets rid of decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Week = ceiling(row_number()/7))

   Date                 Week
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2018-05-24 00:00:00     1
 2 2018-05-25 00:00:00     1
 3 2018-05-26 00:00:00     1
 4 2018-05-27 00:00:00     1
 5 2018-05-28 00:00:00     1
 6 2018-05-29 00:00:00     1
 7 2018-05-30 00:00:00     1
 8 2018-05-31 00:00:00     2
 9 2018-06-01 00:00:00     2
10 2018-06-02 00:00:00     2
```

It does not take into account the dates, it just groups together every 7 rows.

The same with `base R`:

```
ceiling(1:NROW(df)/7)

 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6
```